# JSF2 + Spring + @Transactional

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, spring-boot, transactional

I'm creating project which uses JSF (Primefaces 5.2), Spring (spring-boot 1.2.3.RELEASE) + JPA (Hibernate). I'm using my domain model with Lazy loading. 
Of course I have problem with hibernate `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`.

As I'm using spring in JSF managedBeans (`@Component` annotation and `@Scope` annotation) I just tried to add `@Transactional` annotation to methods which are accessing/manipulating the data.

But this is not working form me either, I still have `LazyInitializationException`.

I just want to ask if this what I did is possible (Use `@Transactional` in JSF managed beans) and if this is good pracitce, even if I use `@Transactional` in my Service layer.

Comment: `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` is something completely different from what you said. It is thrown, when a lazily initialized object is attempted outside the transaction boundary which is not initialized within/during an active transaction. You can use programmatic transactions in JSF/CDI/Spring managed beans but it is not considered to be a good practice either (This is not related to the said problem). You had better separate the business logic in its own place - the service layer which also provides many things out of the box like security, declarative transactions, pooling etc.

Comment: Ok so basically imagine that you have Company class and field List<User> users which are lazy loaded. How do I separete this? Should I create method for getUsersOfCompany which will be in service layer and under transaction? So perhaps methods of service will be getCompany, getUsersOfCompany (which will again load company and then return users), ...?

Comment: I would use fetch joins for many-to-one relationships but in this case, if you use a costly collection fetch in a one-to-many relationship (as it is), Hibernate may warn you against something along the line - `ATTENTION: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!`, if `setFirstResult()`, `setMaxResults()` methods are used. Therefore, it is avoidable. If you need a list of users based on a company, you need to have the list of users returned separately -- by passing a company's identifier and fetching a list of users associated with that company separately.